# Unable to find Default Activity Class Name

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

I am working the process of linking facebook login to my android application. In some tutorial I was asked to register my app with Facebook Developers website where I did everything but I couldnt find "Default Activity Class Name" in my Android Studio I have provided this below manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.evago.evago">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <!-- Front Page -->
        <activity
            android:name=".Frontpage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <!-- Search results activity -->


<activity
        android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Search results activity Ends -->

</application>
```

Please help me in locating the "Default Activity Class Name"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

should be the class containing:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

So its **.Frontpage**

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply ,So should I provide it as a ".Frontpage" or "in.evago.evago.Frontpage" where ever default activity name is asked

Comment: Try the full path, just to be sure :)

Comment: What if I have activity with ` <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`? The one which cater for Deep Links has such category. And Facebook mentions it in their documentation for "Default Activity Class Name": https://developers.facebook.com/products/analytics/quickstarts/android/

I think you should use the one which should be opened when you click on app logo in Facebook advert. Not sure though.

Comment: What if the default activity is `SplashActivity` class?

Answer (score 5):

Frontpage - This is the default activity name because its the launcher activity

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have an app with another Activity without LAUNCHER category, but with DEFAULT category. The one for Deep Linking connection.

Facebook Analytics Quickstart Guide for Android:
`Default Activity Class Name
This is the fully qualified class name of the activity that handles deep linking. We use this when we deep link into your app from the Facebook app. You can also find this in your Android Manifest.`